# Css print style. Different layout for left/right pages?

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to create layout for print with css. I was hoping to alternate the position of the sidebar on left/right pages. 
So basically what I would like is something like:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
}

aside img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

article {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
}

@page {
  margin: 2cm;
  size: 150mm 150mm;
}

@page: left {}

@page: right {
  aside {
    float: right;
  }
  article {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/480/animals" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/480/animals" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/480/animals" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/480/animals" /></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fortitudinis quaedam praecepta sunt ac paene leges, quae effeminari virum vetant in dolore. Hic Speusippus, hic Xenocrates, hic eius auditor Polemo, cuius illa ipsa sessio fuit, quam videmus.
    Sed fortuna fortis; Itaque eos id agere, ut a se dolores, morbos, debilitates repellant. Idem fecisset Epicurus, si sententiam hanc, quae nunc Hieronymi est, coniunxisset cum Aristippi vetere sententia. An dolor longissimus quisque miserrimus, voluptatem
    non optabiliorem diuturnitas facit? Dici enim nihil potest verius. An tu me de L. Primum quid tu dicis breve? Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</p>
  <p>Equidem etiam Epicurum, in physicis quidem, Democriteum puto. Videmus in quodam volucrium genere non nulla indicia pietatis, cognitionem, memoriam, in multis etiam desideria videmus. Tubulo putas dicere? Vitae autem degendae ratio maxime quidem illis
    placuit quieta. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Isto modo ne improbos quidem, si essent boni viri.</p>
  <p>Non est ista, inquam, Piso, magna dissensio. Si verbum sequimur, primum longius verbum praepositum quam bonum. Ne tum quidem te respicies et cogitabis sibi quemque natum esse et suis voluptatibus? Venit enim mihi Platonis in mentem, quem accepimus primum
    hic disputare solitum; Age sane, inquam. Quamquam tu hanc copiosiorem etiam soles dicere.</p>
  <p>Ita est quoddam commune officium sapientis et insipientis, ex quo efficitur versari in iis, quae media dicamus. Eam si varietatem diceres, intellegerem, ut etiam non dicente te intellego; Quid ergo? Potius inflammat, ut coercendi magis quam dedocendi
    esse videantur. Inde igitur, inquit, ordiendum est. Quid enim necesse est, tamquam meretricem in matronarum coetum, sic voluptatem in virtutum concilium adducere? Atque hoc loco similitudines eas, quibus illi uti solent, dissimillimas proferebas.
    Sed quanta sit alias, nunc tantum possitne esse tanta. Mene ergo et Triarium dignos existimas, apud quos turpiter loquare? Iam in altera philosophiae parte.</p>
  <p>Idque testamento cavebit is, qui nobis quasi oraculum ediderit nihil post mortem ad nos pertinere? Qua ex cognitione facilior facta est investigatio rerum occultissimarum. Haec dicuntur fortasse ieiunius; Quamquam id quidem licebit iis existimare, qui
    legerint. Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Itaque nostrum est-quod nostrum dico, artis est-ad ea principia, quae accepimus. Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones. Quae qui non vident, nihil umquam magnum
    ac cognitione dignum amaverunt. Quid est, quod ab ea absolvi et perfici debeat?</p>
</article>
```

I know about the named pages feature of print css, but that only applies to the whole element (article in my case), and the element potentially flows over multiple pages.

Is this possible in CSS?
Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Can you please add your html ?

Comment: I've added some code, but it is obviously not the right solution or I wouldn't be asking :) 
Not sure if floats would be the right approach either. I've been reading through the specs, and I just don't think it is possible: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/